# Detect directwrite chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Page without Directwrite: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pg3s.png

Page with Directwrite: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oelRZ.png

My menu system is setup in such a way it is to the exact pixel, so Directwrite messes up the layout. Granted, a better solution may be to fix the menu system not rely on the exact pixel and that is accept as well but I am mostly looking for a way to detect directwrite as a quick and easy hack.

Site in question: http://www.meyersboat.com/meyers/photos/

Comment: Can't you just simply give the items less padding as a quick fix?

Comment: The last element won't line up with the right side then

Comment: please insert the relevant code in the question itself (more info here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) linking to your website without including relevant code isn't considered good practice on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all caused by directwrite, font-family and font-size, an easy test :

```
function checkForDirectwrite(){
    var test = document.createElement('div');
    test.innerHTML = 'abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    test.setAttribute('style','font-size:11px;visibility:hidden;position:absolute;height:auto;width:auto;white-space:nowrap;top:0px;left:-10000px;z-index:-10');
    document.body.appendChild(test);
    var width = test.clientWidth+1;
    document.body.removeChild(test);
    return width;
}
```

**In your page** :

*Google Chrome (enabled Directwrite) --> 317 px*

*Google Chrome (disabled Directwrite) --> 312 px*

*Firefox --> 310 px*

*IExplorer --> 310 px*

Answer (score 1):

One quick way I got it to work was to add:

```
#sub-navigation {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#sub-navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    /* float: left; */
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

I did reduce the text size for this to fit but this way you can add/remove `padding-left` without it wrapping. I didn't not test on different browsers. Hope that helps.

Comment: This led to a start to what will ultimately be a better fix, but Thanasis answered my question directly, but your solution was more helpful to me